# Showing that stochastic process solves an SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am given

$$
X(t) = (1+W(t)/3)^3
$$

and am asked to show that it solves

$$
dX = \frac{1}{3}X^{1/3}dt + X^{2/3}dW\\
X(0)=1
$$

By using Ito's rule on $X$, it is quite easy to arrive to $dX = \frac{1}{3}X^{1/3}dt + X^{2/3}dW$. So here I go from $X$ to $dX$.

However, this does not make use of the initial condition $X(0)=1$ in any way. In order to use the initial condition, I guess one has to go from $dX$ to $X$. How does one go about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the differential expression of SDE's are shorthand for an integral equation. So you actually do have the expression for $X$ already.
$$
\text{d}X_{t} = \frac{1}{3}X_{t}^{\frac{1}{3}}\text{d}t+X^{\frac{2}{3}}\text{d}W_{t} \iff X_{t} - X_{0} = \frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{t}X_{s}^{\frac{1}{3}}\text{d}s+\int_{0}^{t}X_{s}^{\frac{2}{3}}\text{d}W_{s}
$$
However in your case, it is rather easy to see that $X_{0} = 1$, since you are given
$$
X_{0} = \left( 1 + \frac{W_{0}}{3} \right)^{3} = 1
$$
since $W_{0}=0$ by properties of the Wiener process.